# Database linking with netbeans jframes

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a database name "ward  data base" in which a table names patients has a column "date of admission" whose data type is "date".
Now the problem is when the data is filled in a jframe form it gets updated in that database, all the other data types string but when it comes to get text for the date column it shows error. so what "Get.*datatype*" should i use to get the date entered in the jfield and saved in data base.
Here is the code.

```
     private void UpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
  newentry = new Patients();
    Connection  conn= null;
  PreparedStatement st =null;
    try{


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
}                                      
   catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException |IllegalAccessException ex)
  {
   Logger.getLogger(New_Patient_Entry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null, ex);
   }
    try
   {
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/warddatabase","admin","admin");

   }
    catch(SQLException ex){
    Logger.getLogger(New_Patient_Entry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

}

These are the columns names and there relative jtextfields. In this the date variable shows error

```
    newentry.patientID = pat_id.getText();
    newentry.name = pat_name.getText();
    newentry.age= pat_age.getText();
    newentry.unit=pat_unit.getText();
    newentry.sex=pat_sex.getText();
    newentry.diagonis=diagonisis.getText();
    newentry.dateOfAddmission=DOA.getDate();
    newentry.treatmentPlan=treat_plan.getText();




    String sql1 = "Insert into patients   (Patient_ID,Name,Age,Unit,Sex,Diagonsis,DateOfAddmission,Treatment_Plan) values ('" +newentry.patientID+ "', '"+newentry.name+"', '"+newentry.age+"','"+newentry.unit+"','"+newentry.sex+"','"+newentry.diagonis+"','"+newentry.dateOfAddmission+"','"+newentry.treatmentPlan+"')";


    try {
        st = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    }  
    catch (SQLException ex) {        Logger.getLogger(New_Patient_Entry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        st.executeUpdate(sql1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(New_Patient_Entry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. [Please read this](http://bobby-tables.com) to know what they are and how to prevent them.

Comment: this code is not of SQL. this code of the Jframe form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have i'th column as date in database.

```
java.util.Date date;
Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(i);
if (timestamp != null)
    date = new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime()));
```

Comment: for this i have to add date jar file also?

Comment: Yes, You have to add "java.util.Date" class to the jar file

Comment: and what should i use instead of ".getText" for the date data type?

Comment: If you writing in Eclipse, it will show the required classes accordingly

Comment: Look at the code , I have written it. it's, getTimestamp()

Comment: And What other guy(Barranka) is saying is true, that SQL injection is possible on SqlServer

Comment: sorry i didn't get.. how?

Comment: So, Your SQL sever will be somewhere which you are trying to access. So if I fire query like " Select * from Table-name where 1=1" than its not safe!!    I would say use Hibernate for this.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072999/data-storage/get-started-with-hibernate.html

Comment: I would also recommend you to start using Eclipse (https://eclipse.org/downloads/) if you not using one. And I would also recommend to use maven(http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/) projects.

Comment: but I don't have any idea of using maven projects